# Which Stanislaw Lem works are being referenced in this quote?

Tags: stanislaw-lem

The current issue of the *New Yorker* includes [a long article about Stanislaw Lem](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2022/01/17/a-holocaust-survivors-hardboiled-science-fiction), about new biographies of Lem focusing on the extent to which Lem's Jewish identity and experience of the Holocaust and wartime Poland, which he seldom wrote about, informed his science fiction.

Anyway, at the beginning of the article the author writes

> When [Lem] toured the Soviet Union in the nineteen-sixties, he was
> greeted by cosmonauts and astrophysicists, and addressed
> standing-room-only crowds. A self-described futurologist, he foresaw
> maps that could plot a route at a touch, immersive artificial
> realities, and instant, universal access to knowledge via “an enormous
> invisible web that encircles the world.

I would like to know in which Lem works did he predict virtual reality and the World Wide Web. I feel as though I have read a lot of Lem but don't remember these elements.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From “Dialogi po szesnastu latach”, including the text:  *Losing
Illusions:  From Intelectronics to Information Technology*

The translated portion is:

> “But if as a result of gradual merging
> of computing machines and memory banks there emerge national, continental, and later even ***planetary computer network***, which is a realistic direction of development, the whole system, constituted by humans and these networks, may take up a dynamic trajectory, quite divergent from the civilizational hopes”

With regards to *Virtual Reality*, Lem wrote about "**phantomatics**".

Additionally, this article has a list:

https://culture.pl/en/article/13-things-lem-predicted-about-the-future-we-live-in

The Internet

> In the early 1950s, Lem was already reflecting on the possibility of connecting powerful computers in order to enhance their computing capacity. In his **Dialogues** from 1957, he considered it a realistic direction of development that the gradual accumulation of ‘informatic machines’ and ‘banks of memories’ would lead to establishing ‘state, continental and, later, **planetary computer nets**’.

> Lem, who died in 2006, lived to see many of his predictions come true, including the Internet. And it surprised him. His famous, though apocryphal reaction to his first encounter with the new medium was said to be:

> *Until I used the Internet, I didn’t know there were so many idiots in the world.*

Virtual reality

> With virtual reality technologies and devices lurking in every corner and every commercial, VR may seem like the next hot thing. But Stanisław Lem wrote convincingly about VR (his own term was ‘phantomatics’) back in 1964, long before many Western futurists associated with the term conceived of the idea. In his Summa Technologiae, Lem describes a machine which he calls a ‘phantomaton’, capable of **creating alternative realities** which would be indistinguishable from the ‘original’ reality.

> Moreover, Lem saw this technology as working on multiple layers, meaning that a person leaving one virtual reality wouldn’t necessarily return to the ‘real’ one. Rather, one could switch between different alternative simulations, without ever being sure if this is the ‘original’ reality, or the real world. This obviously would lead to the blurring of the the line between truth and fiction, and Lem obviously saw this as a potential threat:

> *An accretion of illusory realities like this can lead to a situation where real life can also be treated as a manufactured illusion.*